# Using jquery to set php variable value?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I currently have 2 pages:

- **Follow.php**:a PHP page which is all setup with twitters api and will follow any user on twitter with the specific parameter you put in.
- One **index.php** page, which has a list of links of people you can follow.

What I am looking to do is have it so when a user clicks on one of the people to follow on index.php, the variable in follow.php (which is used as a parameter and is the username of twitter account that is going to be followed) gets set to the name attribute of the link selected.

Now I am not the greatest developer, so I am not sure of the best way of doing this.  There is probably a better way of doing it that what I am thinking of.  I was thinking of using jquery to say something like:

```
$('a').click(function(){
<?php $group=?>$(this).attr('name'); //trying to set a php variable to name attr
})
```

This was going to be in its own new file,
then I was going to include this script into the follow.php script and use the variable.  This is not working, unsurprisingly.  I hope I explained what I was trying to do well.

So I have two questions.

Number 1:what is the best way of achieving what I am trying to do?  can i do this all in php?

Number 2: is it possible to do what I was trying to do with jquery and setting the php var equal to the name attr?

Comment: PHP is a server side language. That means everything happens before the page gets to the browser. You can't mix PHP and JS like that. You can make a call using AJAX to your PHP page providing get/post parameters and the server side do whatever you need with that info.

Comment: Can't you just build your links to include that param? e.g. `<a href="follow.php?group=somegroup">follow some group</a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is do a POST on the Follow.php page and accept the username value. This is a great resource for that: http://www.html.net/tutorials/php/lesson10.php

You can simply set the link href for each  tag on the index page to go got Follow.php?user=twitterHandle (where twitterHandle is the twitter username of a person). This way, you dont need to use any javascript at all.

Answer (score 3):

PHP runs on the *server*. JavaScript (jQuery) runs on the *browser*. PHP can be used to write JS, but JS can't affect PHP (except via AJAX or similar).

Comment: Well that is crystal clear. No need to search any further!